# Error inflating class com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton

Tags: java, android, android-layout, twitter, twitter-fabric

Actually i got an error on **Twitter fabric** component **only at ASUS_T00J** device running Android API:19 and SO:4.4.2. The login works fine on almost every Android device except for this one.

Detail cause the Twitter login component cannot be created at a dialog, i did a trick. All the twitter components are initialized at the main activity, but the click event is called from the dialog (by reference i call the click event on the twitter object). Works fine on moto G, samsung etc.

Its something like that caused the error:

```
     Didn't find class "com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/view.infoseg.morettic.com.br.infosegapp-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/view.infoseg.morettic.com.br.infosegapp-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]]
```

Below the full error stacktrace from firebase crash console:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{view.infoseg.morettic.com.br.infosegapp/view.infoseg.morettic.com.br.infosegapp.view.InfosegMain}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #186: Error inflating class com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2318) android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2396) android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:139) android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1293) android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102) android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:149) android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5257) java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:793) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:609) dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java) arrow_drop_down Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #186: Error inflating class com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton arrow_drop_down Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/view.infoseg.morettic.com.br.infosegapp-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/view.infoseg.morettic.com.br.infosegapp-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /system/lib/arm]] dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56) java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:497) java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:457) android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:559) android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:696) android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:755) android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:839) android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:745) android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:839) android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:745) android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:492) android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:397) android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:353) android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onPostCreate (AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java) android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java) view.infoseg.morettic.com.br.infosegapp.view.InfosegMain.onCreate (InfosegMain.java) android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5411) android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1087) android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2270) android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2396) android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:139) android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1293) android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102) android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:149) android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5257) java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:793) com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:609) dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

Below my gradle script

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'
        //classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "view.infoseg.morettic.com.br.infosegapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 45
        versionName "Capsule_Corp1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
    //compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/tappx-sdk-android-v2.3.3.jar')
}
```

Comment: Have you added dependencies for *twitter fabric* ?

Comment: As i said before, the error is happening only at ASUS PHONE. So if it run on others devices i can say YES i DID.

Comment: look at my gradle script.

Comment: Yes gradle script seems look perfect not an issue with that.

Comment: as i said. Happens only on one kind of device :X